# How to display Information Schema using Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, information-schema, biginsights

Is there any way by which we can implement `information_schema` using Hive? Also, What is the process to do data profiling in Hive?
Example in SQL we use `Information_Schema` like this :

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Comment: In [Big SQL 1.0 - Catalog schema](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.bigsql.doc/doc/bsql_catalog_schema.html) can give you some information ;).

Answer (score 2):

information_schema is not implemented in Hive, there is an open [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1010) for the same. By default Hive uses Derby as the metastore to store the table metadata. By connecting to Derby, the system tables can be seen.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. Do you know how to connect to Derby?

Comment: `jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true` is the connect string, `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` is the driver name. By default metastore_db folder will be created in the Hive installation directory where the metadata is stored. Write a Java program or use one of the GUI tools mentioned [here](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UsesOfDerby)

Comment: This is a decent workaround. I note that in May 2017 that JIRA ticket appears to be resolved, and tagged to be released in v 3.0.0. It involves running the schematool to create the sys and information_schema databases. Currently it appears latest is 2.3

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
cnx = pyodbc.connect(dsn = 'Hive', autocommit ='true' )
df = pd.read_sql('DESCRIBE EXTENDED TABLE_NAME;', cnx)
print(df)
```

i use the above code in python but to answer your question you could simply use DESCRIBE EXTENDED TABLE_NAME;